# Using log4net in a complex software

Tags: log4net

I'm using log4net logging in my software that consists of several applications.
I want to have one common library for this.
I created a library and put it in the conficuration file. In AssemblyInfo.cs placed attribute:
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = @"c:\logging.xml", Watch = true)

It work for windows service, but in dosn't work for asp.net application. 
It work in asp.net if delete attribute from common library and put in into global.asax. However, this leads to that section of the log4net configuration must be made in the windows service.

There is also a business process which causes our library through the
remouting. I want the logging was carried out there too.

Is there way around this?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the library should not define where the configuration file is found. Maybe a better idea would be to have a helper method that allows you to configure log4net quickly; that method would take an optional parameter for the config file path and would try to load the configuration file from the specified path first and if that does not work fallback to some maybe the current folder, the application folder or even the web / app.config.

If you insist that it must be an absolute path then you need to give the IIS Application Pool user read access to this file. This way the configuration by attribute should work for services and ASP.Net applications. I do not understand what you mean by "remounting".

Comment: and give the IIS Application Pool user write permissions to logfile

Comment: if a file appender is used then giving write permissions is not enough: either you need minimal locking or (for instance) file names based on process id or else not all application can log at the same time...

Comment: I do not rightly said earlier. By "remouting" I mean loading the assembly through reflection and calling one of its methods. In the calling method used by logging through a common library.

IIS Application Pool has read access to the file. But this does not work in asp.net, if not move configuration attribute directly to the asp.net.

Comment: I see. Not sure why it would not work with the attribute... If you use my first suggestion then your problems will go away...